# Postgres - Use aliased column in subquery

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

Is it possible to take an aliased column from the outer query and use it to filter a subquery. In essential, I'd like to do something like this

```
select distinct 
    array_agg(foo.id) as foo_list,
    (select sum(data) from foo where id in foo_list)
from foo
where x
```

but syntax error at or near "foo_list"

Comment: what is `gmdts_list`?

Comment: I meant to say foo_list, will edit

Comment: Is your `id` not unique in `foo`? Because if it is, you can simplify the subquery to just `sum(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with temp as
(
  select distinct array_agg(foo.id) as foo_list from foo
)
select sum(data) from foo 
where id in (select  foo_list from temp)
```

Comment: The OP's query also returns the `foo_list`